# Render rows within sections using ListView?

Tags: react-native, react-native-listview

With the `ListView` component in react-native - is it possible to render rows within sections like this?

```
<section>
  <row>A</row>
  <row>B</row>
</section>
<section>
  <row>C</row>
  <row>D</row>
</section>
```

And **not** like this:

```
<section></section>
<row>A</row>
<row>B</row>
<section></section>
<row>C</row>
<row>D</row>
```

I'm using renderRow and renderSectionHeader.

The reason I want to render like this is due to the styling. But maybe I'll need to have two nested `ListView` instead?

Comment: What styling you need?

Comment: @farwayer Each <section> should like a card with shadow. Unfortunately that specific look is not possible to accomplish with header, footer and separator.

Answer (score 0):

I can propose a bit hacky solution.

On android to add shadow to secton you can set `elevation` to all rows and section header. On ios you need to set `shadow*` styles.

But you will get problem if you will decide to add `borderRadius`. In this case to prevent top border artifacts you can add small negative `marginBottom` (`-2` or `-4` should be enough) to each row.

```
shadow: {
  shadowOffset: {
    width: 2,
    height: 2
  },
  shadowRadius: 1,
  shadowOpacity: 0.2,
  elevation: 2,
  borderRadius: 2,
  marginBottom: -2,
}
```

ListView with 3 rows:

[image][image]